# Sobre búsqueda con autofiltro en OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice

lo explico de forma gráfica, tengo esto:

| nombre | concepto | cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pepito | peras | 3 |
|  | manzanas | 34 |
|  | platanos | 5 |

Son tres columnas, un registro, la primera columna está unida las otras no, en este caso la proporción es de 1 a 3. Si ejecuto un autofiltro sobre la primera columna y selecciono un "nombre", me muestra la primera fila del registro,mostrando "Pepito  peras 3", no me muestra todas las que tenga, ¿alguna idea para que muestre todo?.

un saludo y gracias....